# NetSuite RESTlet NLAuth using Postman

Tags: json, http, postman, netsuite

I'm new in NetSuite and I tried to make a REST request using Postman I've write in header the NLAuth authorization like the line above:

```
    Authorization : NLAuth nlauth_account=0000000, nlauth_email=at@at.com, nlauth_signature=mypassworld,nlauth_role=3
```

And i follow the process of this tutorial: https://community.boomi.com/docs/DOC-2676#jive_content_id_To_call_the_getRecord_RESTlet

But I receive the following response:

```
    {
        "error": {
          "code": "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT",
          "message": "Invalid login attempt."
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the actual request you are doing into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Postman's built-in Authorization tools to build the correct OAuth1 header: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/authorization

Answer (score 0):

It's best practice to use OAuth so credentials are not exposed. NS uses OAuth 1.0.
Realm = NS Account number
Signature Method can be SHA1 or SHA256

Make sure the "Add params to header" is checked.
Always "Update Request" before sending in order to generate proper Nonce/Timestamp

Add the Content-Type = application/json to the headers

Body must be a valid JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following doc and it help me: [If the URL above don't work click in this link.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKJMk.png)

URL https://system.xx.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_1530099787.html